# How do I add more data for each census tracts in the map?

Tags: r, leaflet, tigris, tidycensus

I was able to prepare census tracts map of a county (showing all census tracts) using **`tidycensus`** and **`tigris`**. I have some data in a separate dataframe called `demography` which contains 4 columns `county`,`tract`, `x.foreclosure_filing`, and `delinquent_parcels`.

How do I create a map of only those tracts that are in the `demography` (only 19 tracts) dataframe and show the value of `x.foreclosure_filing`, and `delinquent_parcels` for these (19) tracts in the map?

demography dataframe looks like this:

```
County      tract           X.foreclosure_filings   delinquent_parcels
1 Cuyahoga 1401.00                     8              13.52
2 Cuyahoga 1403.01                    18              22.25
3 Cuyahoga 1403.02                    18              11.96
4 Cuyahoga 1404.00                    19               8.44
5 Cuyahoga 1405.00                    27              10.93
6 Cuyahoga 1407.01                    17              13.77
```

**code**

```
library(tidycensus)
library(tidyverse)
options(tigris_use_cache = TRUE)


clevelandhts <- get_acs(state = "OH", county = "Cuyahoga", geography = "tract", 
                        variables = "B19013_001", geometry = TRUE)

View(clevelandhts)
clevelandhts %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = estimate)) + 
  geom_sf(color = NA) + 
  coord_sf(crs = 26917) + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "magma")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `fuzzy_join` to merge your two data frames together, with `str_detect` to find the census tract string from `demography` contained within `NAME` in `clevelandhts`. To include information on different columns in the map as labels, use `geom_sf_label`.

**Edit**: The fill color is now based on `X.foreclosure_filings`.

```
library(tidycensus)
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)

options(tigris_use_cache = TRUE)

demography$tract <- as.character(demography$tract)

census_api_key("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")

clevelandhts <- get_acs(state = "OH", county = "Cuyahoga", geography = "tract", 
                        variables = "B19013_001", geometry = TRUE)

clevelandhts %>%
  fuzzy_join(demography, by = c("NAME" = "tract"), match_fun = str_detect) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = X.foreclosure_filings)) + 
  geom_sf(color = NA) + 
  coord_sf(crs = 26917) + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "magma") +
  geom_sf_label(aes(label = X.foreclosure_filings))
```

**Plot**

[image: map with census tracts]

**Data**

```
demography <- read.table(
  text = "County      tract           X.foreclosure_filings   delinquent_parcels
 Cuyahoga 1401.00                     8              13.52
 Cuyahoga 1403.01                    18              22.25
 Cuyahoga 1403.02                    18              11.96
 Cuyahoga 1404.00                    19               8.44
 Cuyahoga 1405.00                    27              10.93
 Cuyahoga 1407.01                    17              13.77", header = T)
```

**Edit (2/29/20)**:

To add street map underneath you can do the following.

In this example, I use a Google street map after entering an API key. The location argument is specific for this example, but the box bounds could be obtained from `clevelandhts` after joining with `demography` table. Again, this is just a demo. If you need further assistance, I would encourage you to post a separate question.

```
# Requires Google API key
county_map <- get_map(location = c(-81.57,41.49,-81.52,41.56), maptype = "roadmap", source = "google")

full_data <- fuzzy_join(clevelandhts, demography, by = c("NAME" = "tract"), match_fun = str_detect)

ggmap(county_map) +
  geom_sf(data = full_data, inherit.aes = FALSE, aes(fill = X.foreclosure_filings)) + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "magma", alpha = .2) +
  geom_sf_label(data = full_data, aes(label = X.foreclosure_filings), inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image: map with street view]

Comment: @How to have give color based on the value of {x.foreclosure_filings}, not the variable {B19013_001} which is in {clevelandhts } data frame? In another word, only use the census tract boundary from the US Census, and plot only my own data {demography} in the map?

Comment: The color that fills in the census tract was based on `estimate` (that's what was in your original code). You can change this to another variable. To have the `fill` color be based on `X.foreclosure_filings` you can do: `ggplot(aes(fill = X.foreclosure_filings))`

Comment: Perfect. Is there a way to add more layers in the map - I need to add streets. And to make the streets visible, I will have to make the colors a little bit transparent.

Comment: @Posh - To have your fill color be transparent, you can add `alpha` such as: `scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "magma", alpha = .2)`. Try it out with your current map to visualize what this looks like. As for streets, yes - you can add streets. Perhaps take a look at this [blog](https://dominicroye.github.io/en/2018/accessing-openstreetmap-data-with-r/) or this [demo](https://ggplot2tutor.com/streetmaps/streetmaps/) that use Openstreetmap, or [this](https://www.littlemissdata.com/blog/maps) for a tutorial on Google Map (`ggmap`). You might want a separate question about adding street mapping.

Comment: I read all the links and tutorials for adding the street layer in the map, but still unable to do so.  `ggplot() +
+     geom_sf(data = small_streets$osm_lines,
+             inherit.aes = FALSE,
+             color = "black",
+             size = .4,
+             alpha = .8) +
+     coord_sf(xlim = c(-81.52, -81.61), 
+              ylim = c(41.48, 41.55),
+              expand = FALSE)`  This doesn't produce any street map for the map we already created (in your answer).

Comment: I did edit the answer to provide an example with a street view using a Google map (API key required). This really needs further work, but hopefully this example will provide you with future direction. For additional assistance consider posting a separate question on this topic. If this answer is helpful, please upvote or accept answer. Good luck!